File Directory Not Working - Mac/Unix System
Background:  I'm using Mac/Unix and writing code in C on visual studio.
I'm attempting to copy an excel file from my computer's directory into the character array "filedata," using a relative file path.  In order to accomplish this, I'm copying the current working directory (using the getcwd() function) into the Fileaddr character array, then appending the filename onto the end of the current directory string.  Unfortunately, the fopen() function keeps failing to open as evidenced by the "failure" text that keeps printing as a result of fp being NULL.  I've tested within both visual studio and the terminal directly.
In order to test the above, I've printed the string in my program being sent to fopen() via puts(concatenated value of string).  From there, I've sent the command "open [filepath copied directly from visual studio printed text within the terminal]" and the file opens correctly in excel.  When I type the above without the "open" command, I get a "permission denied" error (not sure this has something to do with the issue.  In any event, my code is below.  Any advice for figuring out what the issue is or how I can go about troubleshooting it?
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXADDRSIZE 10000
#define MAXFILESIZE 1000000

int main()
{
    char Fileaddr[MAXADDRSIZE];
    getcwd(Fileaddr, MAXADDRSIZE);
    char Filedata[MAXFILESIZE];
    strncat(Fileaddr, "/MonthlyStateReport.xlsx\0", 30);
    puts(Fileaddr);
    FILE * fp=fopen(Fileaddr, "R");
    if(fp==NULL)puts("failure");
    fclose(fp);
}


Remember that C is case-sensitive. That also includes strings like "R". Now please take some time to think about when you learned how to use the fopen function, what was you taught to use?

Possible buffer overrun with strncat().

When you get a failure from a library routine, do not just print “failure”. Print the value of errno (and include the <errno.h> header) or use perror("fopen"); to print a message about the error. In this case, it would have told you “Invalid argument”, which could have led to you investigate why the arguments to fopen were invalid.

The capital R seems to be the issue.  Thank you everyone!  Using Perno() definitely seems like a useful tool.

As noted, the capital "R" was an issue.  Also, to be a bit more robust, it would be good to not attempt closing a file if the pointer value is invalid (e.g. NULL).  One such method would be to place your notification of "failure" along with a "return" of some value (e.g. 1) within a code block conditioned by the "if" test you have.  Otherwise, when I tested the program it produces a segmentation fault.

Aside: "/MonthlyStateReport.xlsx\0" is a string literal so it will have a nul terminator anyway.

Yea, I kept wondering why I was getting an annoying segmentation fault.  That fclose() on a failed fopen(), not a buffer overflow was causing it.  I also wanted to ensure the file path was exact.
